# Is that possible to add destroy action into _form.html.erb instead of index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

If I do scaffold, it automatically makes destroy action in index.html.erb.
What if I want to move this action to _form.html.erb?
And I'd like to make it appear only during edit mode(example.com/books/1212/edit)
not during new mode(example.com/books/new)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would help you

*model*

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :delete_flag #with other attributes
  attr_accessor :delete_flag
end
```

*in your view (_form)*

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
  #other code
  <%= f.text_field :delete_flag%>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
    <%= f.submit "Delete",{:class => "delete_button"} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

*coffeescript*

```
jQuery ->
  $('#new_job').submit -> 
    #capture your delete button click
    $('#job_delete_flag').val("1")
```

in your controller you will get params as `:delete_flag`, and from there you could

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5oWQU+w0jVCQlw8wLvCyKajbBSKpK2sv6RMkSGTE2H8=", "job"=>{"delete_flag"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Delete"}
```

HTH

Comment: thanks! <%= f.text_field :delete_flag%> what does this do? I thought you will prepare hidden field or something

Comment: yep, it should be a hidden field, sorry my bad :D

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but make sure when you click on the delete button it does not file the form submit action.

You might consider using `:remote => true` for delete link and you could check if the record is new or existing by using:

```
<Object>.new_record?
```

Ex: if I have a model called Job

```
Job.first.new_record? #=> false

Job.new.new_record?   #=> true
```

Ex: something like (not tested :D, just to give you an idea)

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
  #your form content
  <%= f.submit %>
  <%= (link_to 'Destroy', @job, :remote => true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }) unless @job.new_record? %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I don't want remote=true:( I want make it submit style because I have before_filter to check if the post is owned by current_user and captcha_check before delete

Comment: @HUSTEN, in that case I think you might need to do some more work, but possible work around is, set a delete flag and send the data to your controllers 'update' action then from there u could handle the  delete upon the flag. in your view, have 'Edit', 'Delete' buttons but both will file the update action

Comment: ahhh, yeah I've done something like that with deletion of paper clip attached file. so I have to make something like this? <%= f.check_box :image_delete, :label => 'Delete Image' %>　Delete Image          There's no option to put just the button inside of the form for destroy action??

Comment: yeah sort ok, use Jquery to set an inner delet flag (to a hidden text field) before submitting the form, by what way you can get what you want from the controller end

Comment: I think I'm okay to prepare the flag coding in model. The thing I wanna know is how to make the button with hidden inside of the form.

Comment: Let me explain my situation to you again.  I have _form.html.erb, in which usual form_tag is used here. I have simple_captcha to verify before update. I'd like to have delete button to destroy record. But nothing like default. I want user to type captcha word in the same box before it execute destroy action.  How would you design routes, controller and form in view?

Comment: I have posted a new answer, check that out :D